# Varnish as port forwarder should not store the entire HTTP request before forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, varnish

I want to use Varnish to listen at port 80 and forward the HTTP requests to different local ports, based on the hostname. Each hostname represent a different Rails application.

Is it default behavior of Varnish not to store the entire HTTP request before forwarding. IF not, what is the configuration setting called?

I'm new to Varnish. I have chosen Varnish instead of HAProxy, because I don't need load balancing  and might make use of caching later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't caching, you might as well just use `return(pipe);`, which will have Varnish simply pass raw data between client and backend.